# How can I stop my MySQL server from going down?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, server-crashes

I have a website based on a MySQL server on an Ubuntu machine. Every several weeks, one of my users complains that the site does not work, and I find out (using `service mysql status`) that it is because the MySQL server is down. I restart it (using `service mysql restart`) and the site starts working fine again.
In `/var/log/mysql/error.log`, the only error messages I see are of the form `[ERROR] [MY-013134] [Server] Table 'XXX' is marked as crashed and should be repaired`. But, after I restart the server, I do not see any issue with the tables (I am not sure if this is the reason for the server going down).

These frequent failures are quite a nuisance both for me and for my users. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: My immediate thought is disk drive hardware. Have you tried moving your tables to a different drive? Have you looked for drive errors?

Comment: @tsc_chazz I am on shared hosting (DigitalOcean) so I do not have direct access to the drive.

Comment: **1)** install & configure proper monitoring and alerting so that you can respond to issues before your users start complaining. **2)** When a service fails : do a proper root cause analysis what circumstances caused that failure because many things are possible : running out of resources (disk, memory, or something else) , failure (of hardware, network connectivity), caused by badly constructed queries, spikes in visitors, increased data sets etc etc —- At the moment you don’t show that you did much looking for that cause, so we can only guess. Check your logs, system and MySQL logs first

Comment: @HBruijn I looked at the logs, and all I saw was a note on a table crash.

Answer (score 2):

If you running out of disk space or a similar unexpected event, some of the database tables may have become corrupt.

To solve this you need to run this from MYSQL.

REPAIR TABLE db_name.table_name;

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the table is declared `ENGINE=MyISAM`.  This old engine has the problem that abrupt shutdowns cause that error message.  As already noted `REPAIR TABLE` (for each table involved) is the manual fix.

The long-term solution is to switch to `ENGINE=InnoDB`.  That engine avoids *that* problem and self-repairs most other problems.

The engine change will eventually be mandatory, as MyISAM is being phased out.

Comment: This is not a bad advice, but it absolutely doesn't address the depicted problem, nor the real cause. Also it would be good to see an instructions *how* to do that.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov - MyISAM's flaws + a crash are the cause; `REPAIR TABLE` is the quick cure.  InnoDB is a better cure.

Comment: You can't change engine without fixing table first. Also, "flaws", well, not, bad design maybe, but it served us well for 25+ years, there could be no deadly "flaws" that cause random table breaks, so it couldn't be the "cause". Crash yes, and I am sure it is broken once and wasn't repaired and now it crashes each time it tries to access the table; simple "repair" will fix it and it won't crash anymore. So it's not a "cure" but "stronger prevention from happening again". REPAIR is mandatory in this case, InnoDB is optional.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov - Here are the steps to reproduce it:  1) open a MyISAM table; 2) kill mysqld or reboot the server; 3) restart mysqld.  It is OK to call it a bug in MyISAM, and point out that it has been there for 25+ years.

Comment: Tips on converting to InnoDB:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: I had the same problem on a MyISAM table due to power failures. The solution, I changed to InnoDB and replacement of the backup sources.